# Paperjs : Canvas height and width gets changed on window resize. How to prevent the change?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I have a simple canvas with paperjs configured. while resizing the window canvas height and widths gets change. Thanks folks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"  height="800" width="1000"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var InIt = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    console.log(canvas);
    paper.setup(canvas);
    var path = new paper.Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    var start = new paper.Point(100, 100);
    path.moveTo(start);
    path.lineTo(start.add([200, -50]));
    paper.view.draw();   
}

window.onload = InIt;

window.onresize=InIt;
```

**Screenshot**

Screen 1
[image]

Screen 2

[image]

You can see the height and width differences on resize.

Comment: Yes it does! I presume you are not making a statement but rather asking a question, but you will have to spell that question out for us to know what it is :)  If you don't want it to resize, don't add the init function to resize event.

Comment: @Blindman67 The value should not change for height and width on resize.

Comment: Then do not resize the canvas when the page resizes by not attaching the `Init` function to `window.resize`

Comment: @Blindman67 you are right. but i need window resize option for some other manipulation in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do paper.setup() in the init function. Execute paper.setup() once. Something like the following (my test.html file):

```
<script src="./dist/paper-core.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" height="800" width="1000"></canvas>

<script>
var  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
paper.setup(canvas);
var init = function() {
    console.log(canvas);
    var path = new paper.Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    var start = new paper.Point(100,100);
    path.moveTo(start);
    path.lineTo(start.add([200, -50]));
    paper.view.draw();
}
window.onload = init;
window.onresize = init;
</script>
```

Comment: its gives an error paper.js:2687 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_eventCounters' of undefined

Comment: I used paper 0.9.25. What version are you using?

Comment: I have 0.9.15 paperjs

Comment: This runs fine for me with paper-core.js versions 0.9.15 and 0.9.25. I'm running Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 m on Windows 7 64-bit and Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. Maybe something got copied slightly incorrectly? Note that I did change the canvas ID.

Comment: I get a similar error if the canvas ID used in `document.getElementById()` doesn't match.